# open a file under cursor in a split window

Tags: vim, vi

I often jump from a file to file,  while working  a large codebase. I typically do this by way of  putting cursor on the file, say foo.h, and typing "gf". I wonder if I can do the same thing, yet open the file in a split window.

One obvious solution is to simply type: vsp (sp) filename.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`<c-w>gf`  open in a new tab (`Ctrl-w gf`)

`<c-w>f` for split window <-- this is the answer you are seeking (`Ctrl-w f`)

source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor

Comment: Nice -- I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Yes, new to me too -- just discovered while trying to answer the question. For enjoying tabs, see: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html

Comment: Is there a way make working this with line – if there is `/path/to/file.txt:22` – file:line to jump to the file? Something like [file_line.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184).

Answer (score 4):

When I do `:sp` or `:vs`, the new window is created, but my cursor is left on the same line. Thus, you could do `:sp` followed by `gf`. You could also make a shortcut command or mapping for that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I use a.vim plugin for this. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31

In addition to what you are looking for. I also has a feature in which you can alternate between header and cpp file very easily(if you work on c/cpp code). Its very handy sometimes

Answer (score 0):

If you put this line into your _vimrc:

```
map <F2> <C-w>f:call MoveWindowToRight(1)<CR>
```

you can open the file name under the cursor with F2 and it will appear at the right side of you current window.
This is the best match to your mentioned 'obvious solution' using :vsplit.